# Windows 10 update cannot connect (behind a firewall)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, pfsense

Why Windows 10 Update cannot connect to its update servers even though there is a working internet connection?

[image: Screenshot of Windows 10 Update unable to connect]

About my setup

- Running Windows 10 on a PC behind a dedicated firewall (pfsense 2.2.5)
- There is internet connectivity, port 80 / 443 works fine for anything else
- Connecting the Windows 10 PC directly to my ISP's modem allows to update Windows 10 => suggests that the firewall is causing the problem

Already checked

- pfsense forum with the result that Windows 10 update should work without any hick-ups (not running any proxy)
- Found and tried the resolutions mentioned in the MS Support article [Can't download updates from Windows Update from behind a firewall or proxy server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084568)

Still, Windows 10 (version 1511) cannot update itself when I run it behind my firewall.

Any other suggestions/ideas?

Comment: If you feel like down-voting my question then also feel free to leave a comment why. This problem kept me busy investigating and trying out different things for some time - and there was no obvious fix or google answer to begin with.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I need to try out that firewall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I found the [Windows Update Troubleshooter for Win10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-troubleshooter) from MS.

While running it, it in fact found and fixed a problem. After that, my Windows 10 can update itself now (great).

So, even though everything suggested a problem with my pfSense firewall it was some problem with the Windows Update itself.

Comment: Glad you resolved the problem.